# css / background size is not working in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to my background image to fix on the screen of the browser without any scroll. I have tried every CSS property which is available but still its appearing. I have attached the image to understand better

[image: SCREENSHOT]

And my css code is

```js
particlesJS("particles-js", {
  "particles": {
    "number": {
      "value": 30,
      "density": {
        "enable": true,
        "value_area": 320
      }
    },
    "color": {
      "value": "#ffffff"
    },
    "shape": {
      "type": "circle",
      "stroke": {
        "width": 0,
        "color": "#000000"
      },
      "polygon": {
        "nb_sides": 5
      },
      "image": {
        "src": "img/github.svg",
        "width": 100,
        "height": 100
      }
    },
    "opacity": {
      "value": 0.5,
      "random": false,
      "anim": {
        "enable": false,
        "speed": 1,
        "opacity_min": 0.1,
        "sync": false
      }
    },
    "size": {
      "value": 2,
      "random": true,
      "anim": {
        "enable": false,
        "speed": 25,
        "size_min": 0.1,
        "sync": false
      }
    },
    "line_linked": {
      "enable": true,
      "distance": 150,
      "color": "#ffffff",
      "opacity": 0.4,
      "width": 1
    },
    "move": {
      "enable": true,
      "speed": 6,
      "direction": "none",
      "random": false,
      "straight": false,
      "out_mode": "out",
      "bounce": false,
      "attract": {
        "enable": false,
        "rotateX": 600,
        "rotateY": 1200
      }
    }
  },
  "interactivity": {
    "detect_on": "canvas",
    "events": {
      "onhover": {
        "enable": true,
        "mode": "grab"
      },
      "onclick": {
        "enable": true,
        "mode": "push"
      },
      "resize": true
    },
    "modes": {
      "grab": {
        "distance": 140,
        "line_linked": {
          "opacity": 1
        }
      },
      "bubble": {
        "distance": 400,
        "size": 40,
        "duration": 2,
        "opacity": 8,
        "speed": 3
      },
      "repulse": {
        "distance": 200,
        "duration": 0.4
      },
      "push": {
        "particles_nb": 4
      },
      "remove": {
        "particles_nb": 2
      }
    }
  },
  "retina_detect": true
});


/* ---- stats.js config ---- */
```

```css
canvas {
  display: block;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}


/* ---- particles.js container ---- */

#particles-js {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#particles-js:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
   background-size: cover;
  background-image: url("https://blackshellmedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/Commercial-Buildings.jpg");
  overflow: hidden;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat:   no-repeat;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  -webkit-filter: blur(4px);
  -moz-filter: blur(4px);
  -o-filter: blur(4px);
  -ms-filter: blur(4px);
  filter: blur(4px);
}
```

```html
<div id="particles-js"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/particlesjs/2.1.0/particles.js" defer="defer"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/particles.js/2.0.0/particles.min.js"></script>
```

Please Find the result of my code you will find the error which I am facing.

Comment: If you never want the window to scroll add `html, body {
  overflow: hidden;
}` to your CSS.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Its already added. But still, I am getting the scroll. You can check in my CSS code

Comment: Are you sure? As it works fine for the example you gave above. Scrollbars appear without overflow: https://jsfiddle.net/s8v9arbm, and disappear when it's applied: https://jsfiddle.net/s8v9arbm/1/

Comment: Also note that you can remove the `margin` from the `body` if you want to retain the overflow settings: https://jsfiddle.net/s8v9arbm/2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bydefault `body` tag take some margin, you can set `margin:0;` to fix this problem.  check updated snippet below...

```js
particlesJS("particles-js", {
  "particles": {
    "number": {
      "value": 30,
      "density": {
        "enable": true,
        "value_area": 320
      }
    },
    "color": {
      "value": "#ffffff"
    },
    "shape": {
      "type": "circle",
      "stroke": {
        "width": 0,
        "color": "#000000"
      },
      "polygon": {
        "nb_sides": 5
      },
      "image": {
        "src": "img/github.svg",
        "width": 100,
        "height": 100
      }
    },
    "opacity": {
      "value": 0.5,
      "random": false,
      "anim": {
        "enable": false,
        "speed": 1,
        "opacity_min": 0.1,
        "sync": false
      }
    },
    "size": {
      "value": 2,
      "random": true,
      "anim": {
        "enable": false,
        "speed": 25,
        "size_min": 0.1,
        "sync": false
      }
    },
    "line_linked": {
      "enable": true,
      "distance": 150,
      "color": "#ffffff",
      "opacity": 0.4,
      "width": 1
    },
    "move": {
      "enable": true,
      "speed": 6,
      "direction": "none",
      "random": false,
      "straight": false,
      "out_mode": "out",
      "bounce": false,
      "attract": {
        "enable": false,
        "rotateX": 600,
        "rotateY": 1200
      }
    }
  },
  "interactivity": {
    "detect_on": "canvas",
    "events": {
      "onhover": {
        "enable": true,
        "mode": "grab"
      },
      "onclick": {
        "enable": true,
        "mode": "push"
      },
      "resize": true
    },
    "modes": {
      "grab": {
        "distance": 140,
        "line_linked": {
          "opacity": 1
        }
      },
      "bubble": {
        "distance": 400,
        "size": 40,
        "duration": 2,
        "opacity": 8,
        "speed": 3
      },
      "repulse": {
        "distance": 200,
        "duration": 0.4
      },
      "push": {
        "particles_nb": 4
      },
      "remove": {
        "particles_nb": 2
      }
    }
  },
  "retina_detect": true
});


/* ---- stats.js config ---- */
```

```css
canvas {
  display: block;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}


/* ---- particles.js container ---- */

#particles-js {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#particles-js:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
   background-size: cover;
  background-image: url("https://blackshellmedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/Commercial-Buildings.jpg");
  overflow: hidden;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat:   no-repeat;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  -webkit-filter: blur(4px);
  -moz-filter: blur(4px);
  -o-filter: blur(4px);
  -ms-filter: blur(4px);
  filter: blur(4px);
}


body {
  margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="particles-js"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/particlesjs/2.1.0/particles.js" defer="defer"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/particles.js/2.0.0/particles.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: what i should write if i completely don't want hight scroll also

Comment: @NikitaAgrawal you can use `overflow:hidden;` in body tag.